# Do I need to checkout and pull a remote git branch before I merge it in?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-flow

My normal process for merging in `develop` to my `feature\my-feature` branch is:

```
name@home ~/myRepo (feature/my-feature)
$ git checkout develop
$ git pull
$ git checkout feature/my-feature
$ git merge develop
$ git mergetool
```

Can this be replaced with:

```
name@home ~/myRepo (feature/my-feature)
$ git fetch
$ git merge origin/develop
$ git mergetool
```

Does `fetch` retrieve enough information about the changes from the remote `origin/develop` to allow me to merge from `origin/develop` rather than `develop`?

Is it bad practice to have `feature/my-feature` ahead of `develop` with changes from the remote `origin/develop`?

Comment: Can I just `git pull develop` into my `feature/my-feature`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly `pull` your remote branch `develop`, but you may need to mention the remote repository (in your case, `origin`):

```
git checkout feature
git pull origin develop
```

This will result in a merge commit, where the message mentions `origin/develop`.

Without mentioning the remote repo, I'm afraid that the merge part of the `pull` would merge your local branch `develop`, not the fetched one. But do try it!

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-are-the-differences-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch), `git pull` is just a `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.

It's easier for me to think in such terms.

I personally prefer fetching remote branches rather than pulling them, because automatic merge, forced by `git pull` is not always needed.

Here's how my typical workflow looks like:
I always start new features from `origin/develop` branch

```
git checkout develop
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/develop
git checkout -b new_feature_branch
```

This ensures I am on a latest origin develop branch.

Why it's better than `pull`? Because it prevents merge on fetching and helps maintain clean git history.

Comment: How do you merge the latest to your feature branches to prevent conflicts when your changes are pulled into the remote `develop`? That seems like more commands, not fewer.

Comment: I'll add my typical workflow in my answer in a minute

Comment: In your typical workflow, how do you ensure that `new_feature_branch` is up to date with `develop` before you merge it back in? You should regularly be merging `develop` down into `new_feature_branch` so you merge little and often.

Comment: I usually only merge before pull request. Why am I merging little and often?

Comment: It depends on the team size, the amount of churn/commits on upstream branches, collisions in files. If you you have a complex merge, the smaller the merge and the sooner to when the other contributor commited, the fresher it will be in minds and easier to merge. E.g. Merging in something complex on a friday afternoon after a lunchtime pint that was worked on 9 days ago, with the contributor on annual leave that could have been merged the week before is suboptimal.

Comment: But if you are working in a big team with a lot of changes, you will have to merge often anyways. I guess we were talking about initial branch creation.